# Splitting field of
$f(x) :=x^3+3x^2+3x-4$ over $\Bbb{Q}$ and $\Bbb{Z}_3$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, splitting-field

> We want to find the splitting field of $$f(x) :=x^3+3x^2+3x-4 $$ over
>    $\Bbb{Q}$ and $\Bbb{Z}_3$.

**Attempt.** As usual, we are searching for all the roots in over $\Bbb{Q}$ and $\Bbb{Z}_3$.

In $\Bbb{Z}_3$, it is not difficult to observe that $f(x) = (x-1)^3$, so the splitting field is the same, $\Bbb{Z}_3$.

And I faced a difficulty in $\Bbb{Q}$. One can write our polynomial in the form $f(x) =(x+1)^3-(5^{1/3})^3$ and  find all the roots with the obvious analysis. But, is there another more simple and elegant way?

*Thank you.*

Comment: Splitting fields of $f(x)$ and $f(x-1)$ are equal. And as you noticed $f(x-1)= x^3-5$, so splitting field is $\mathbb Q(\sqrt[3]5,\varepsilon_3)$ where $\varepsilon_3$ is the third primitive root of $1$.

Comment: @SMM Thank you for your comment. Why do these 2 polynomials have the same splitting field? Could I find somewhere the proof?

Comment: If $\alpha$ is a zero of $f(x),$ then $\alpha+1$ is a zero of $f(x-1),$ and the splitting field of $f(x)$ is generated by the zeros of $f(x).$ Do you see how the result follows?

Comment: Actually it is easy. Just note that $\alpha$ is a root of $f(x)$ iff $\alpha+1$ is a root of $f(x-1)$. So, if $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ are roots of $f(x)$, then the splitting field of $f(x)$ is $\mathbb Q(\alpha, \beta, \gamma)$, and the splitting field of $f(x-1)$ is $\mathbb Q(\alpha+1,\beta+1,\gamma+1)= \mathbb Q(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)$.

Comment: Over $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$, the polynomial is $(x-1)^3$.

Comment: @SMM Clear! Thank you very much.

Comment: @egreg Fixed. Thank you.